# OneNote Randomly Closing

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

Have any of you experienced Microsoft OneNote randomly closing 3-5 seconds after it opens?

I've tried uninstall / reinstalling it.
I've also tried doing online repair.
Finally, I have tried clearing my cache.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I notice that if I do not type anything at all, it does not close out. It only closes out after 3-5 seconds when I start typing stuff. I do not believe that it matters what I am typing.

**Edit #2:**

When I look at event viewer, I see this:

```
Log Name: Application
Source: Application Error
Event ID: 1000
Level Error
OpCode: Info
Task Category (100)
```

Comment: Try disabling Hardware Acceleration in One Note options (any Office app options). Close out. Restart the computer and test.

Comment: Okay, stay tuned.

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Try Windows 10 initial repairs :  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(1) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(3) SFC /SCANNOW   Restart and test

Comment: Okay, stay tuned.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new test Account, run One Note and see if it crashes the same way. You could have Profile damage.

Comment: I added some notes about the error

Comment: You could get those Event Viewer errors when a user profile causes One Note to close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

I cleared my OneNote cache when the menu appears that asks me if I want to start normally, clear the cache, etc.

I then restarted my computer.

I opened up the old OneNote book.

Everything appeared to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling the office suite (in all languages), rebooting, and re-installing.